# DirectoryIterator() somehow duplicating the path

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, directory, image-gallery

I am trying to iterate through a directory and display all the pictures inside. I got it to work until I added Jquery/ajax into the equation.. Somehow the path is getting duplicated along the way so I get this error (you can see where it is duplicated):

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(images/gallery/album1,images/gallery/album1) [<a href='directoryiterator.--construct'>directoryiterator.--construct</a>]: The system cannot find the path specified`

I can not for the life of me figure out why it is coming out like that...`contruct(images/gallery/album1,images/gallery/album1)`   should be  `construct(images/gallery/album1)`

PHP:

> ```
> $album = $_POST['album'];
> $dir = new DirectoryIterator("images/gallery/$album");
> foreach ($dir as $fileInfo)
> {
>     if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
>     $pic = $fileInfo->getFilename();
>     print "<div>
>             <img src='images/gallery/$album/$pic'>
>             </div>";
> }
> ```

Jquery/ajax:

> ```
> function albumChosen(id)
> {
> var id = id;
> var album = $('a[id="'+id+'"]').attr("rel");
> $.ajax({
>     url: "PHPscripts/getAlbums.php",
>     type: "POST",
>     data: {'album' : album},
>     success: function(data){
>         $('#galleryList').html(data);
>     }
> });
> return false;
> ```
>
> }

If I `alert(album);` it displays 'album1' correctly. So it has something to do with how its reading it from the `$_POST`

EDIT: 
I added the code suggested..

```
$album = $_POST['album'];
print_r($_POST);
var_dump($album);
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("images/gallery/$album");
//rest of code...
```

`print_r($_POST)` prints out  `Array ( [album] => album1 )`
`var_dump($album)` prints out `string 'album1' (length=6)`

Comment: It seems `$_POST['album']` contains a bad value, such as 'album1,images/gallery/album1'

Comment: according to Firebug, under the POST tab it only sends "album1" like it should.

Comment: You should try `print_r($_POST)` and `var_dump($album)` after the assignment, to shed some light.

Comment: @canaaerus I added the code suggested.. I edited my question above with the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add `../` to the front of my path.. If it didn't duplicate the path the way it did I may have figured this out sooner, but because of that I didn't think there was anything wrong with the path. So here is the complete code that works, again all I added was the `../` in front of the path.

```
$album = $_POST['album'];
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("../images/gallery/$album");
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo)
{
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    $pic = $fileInfo->getFilename();

    print "<div>
                <img src='images/gallery/$album/$pic'>
            </div>";
}
```